# How to use jQuery for listening if checkbox is changed not by clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a number of checkboxes that change state(checked ,not checked) using another jQuery statement:

Elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="select_a">select group A</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="select_b">select group B</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="mix">select mix</input>

<div id="group_a">
    <input type="checkbox" id="a_1">group A_1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" id="a_2">group A_2</input>
</div>
<div id="group_b">
    <input type="checkbox" id="b_1">group B_1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" id="b_2">group B_2</input>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery("#select_a").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) jQuery("div#group_a input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    else jQuery("div#group_a input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
});
jQuery("#select_b").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) jQuery("div#group_b input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
    else jQuery("div#group_b input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
});
jQuery("#mix").click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        jQuery("#a_1").prop("checked", true);
        jQuery("#b_1").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        jQuery("#a_1").prop("checked", false);
        jQuery("#b_1").prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

I need a way to set a listener to each checkbox in the groups, I used this way which works like this:

```
jQuery("div input:checkbox").click(function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
});
```

but this only works if the checkbox was clicked by the mouse, I would like a way to fire an event(set a listener) for each checkbox if it was checked by something other than the mouse.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v091qa5x/)

Comment: Checking the box with the keyboard acts as if you'd clicked it, and triggers the `.click()` handler. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler

```
jQuery("div input:checkbox").change(function(){
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `change` event, also for the top controls use `radio` instead of checkbox as any one would be checked:

```js
$(function() {
  var grp1 = $('#group_a').find('input[type=checkbox]');
  var grp2 = $('#group_b').find('input[type=checkbox]');
  $('input[name=grp]').on('change', function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    grp1.prop('checked', 'select_a' === id);
    grp2.prop('checked', 'select_b' === id);
    if ('mix' === id) {
      grp1.eq(0).prop('checked', true);
      grp2.eq(0).prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- use radio with name -->
<input type="radio" name="grp" id="select_a" />select group A
<input type="radio" name="grp" id="select_b" />select group B
<input type="radio" name="grp" id="mix" />select mix

<div id="group_a">
  <input type="checkbox" id="a_1" />group A_1
  <input type="checkbox" id="a_2" />group A_2
</div>
<div id="group_b">
  <input type="checkbox" id="b_1" />group B_1
  <input type="checkbox" id="b_2" />group B_2
</div>
```